# cross browser compare document position

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, shim, dom4

[DOM4 compareDocumentPosition](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-node-comparedocumentposition)

I want to implement compareDocumentPosition. Resig has made a [great start at doing just this](http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/). I've taken his code and neatened it up

```
function compareDocumentPosition(other) {
    var ret = 0;
    if (this.contains) {
        if (this !== other && this.contains(other)) {
            ret += 16;
        }
        if (this !== other && other.contains(this)) {
            ret += 8;
        }
        if (this.sourceIndex >= 0 && other.sourceIndex >= 0) {
            if (this.sourceIndex < other.sourceIndex) {
                ret += 4;
            }
            if (this.sourceIndex > other.sourceIndex) {
                ret += 2;
            }
        } else {
            ret += 1;
        }
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

This works for `Element` but does not for `Text` or `DocumentFragment`. This is because IE8 does not give `.sourceIndex` on those nodes. (It doesn't give `.contains` either but I've fixed that problem already)

How do I efficiently write the `+=4` and `+=2` bit which correspond to [DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-node-document_position_preceding) and [DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-node-document_position_preceding).

For extra reference those two are defined by tree-order which DOM4 defines as

> An object A is preceding an object B if A and B are in the same tree and A comes before B in tree order.
>
> An object A is following an object B if A and B are in the same tree and A comes after B in tree order.
>
> The tree order is preorder, depth-first traversal.

Most modern browsers implement this (including IE9). So you only need something that works in IE8 (I don't care about IE6/7, but if it works awesome!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function recursivelyWalk(nodes, cb) {
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var ret = cb(node);
        if (ret) {
            return ret;
        }
        if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
            var ret = recursivelyWalk(node.childNodes, cb);
            if (ret) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}

function testNodeForComparePosition(node, other) {
    if (node === other) {
        return true;
    }
}

function compareDocumentPosition(other) {
    function identifyWhichIsFirst(node) {
        if (node === other) {
            return "other";
        } else if (node === reference) {
            return "reference";
        }
    }

    var reference = this,
        referenceTop = this,
        otherTop = other;

    if (this === other) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (referenceTop.parentNode) {
        referenceTop = referenceTop.parentNode;
    }
    while (otherTop.parentNode) {
        otherTop = otherTop.parentNode;
    }

    if (referenceTop !== otherTop) {
        return Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED;
    }

    var children = reference.childNodes;
    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        children,
        testNodeForComparePosition.bind(null, other)
    );
    if (ret) {
        return Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY +
            Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING;
    }

    var children = other.childNodes;
    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        children, 
        testNodeForComparePosition.bind(null, reference)
    );
    if (ret) {
        return Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS +
            Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING;
    }

    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        [referenceTop],
        identifyWhichIsFirst
    );
    if (ret === "other") {
        return Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING;
    } else {
        return Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING;
    }
}
```

I wrote it myself. I thought this implementation was bugged but it was a bug in some other code of mine. Seems pretty solid.

Comment: Oh Raynos, you awesome. Thanks for answering my question

Comment: @TimDown I havn't slept enough.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Raynos is a top start, but is not runnable out of the box. `Node.*` cannot be found and `.bind` is not available in IE8.

Here is the code ready for use in Internet Explorer 8:

```
function recursivelyWalk(nodes, cb) {
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i];
        var ret = cb(node);
        if (ret) {
            return ret;
        }
        if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
            var ret = recursivelyWalk(node.childNodes, cb);
            if (ret) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}

function testNodeForComparePosition(node, other) {
    if (node === other) {
        return true;
    }
}

var DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED = 1;
var DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING = 2;
var DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING = 4;
var DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS = 8;
var DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY = 16;

function compareDocumentPosition(thisNode, other) {
    function identifyWhichIsFirst(node) {
        if (node === other) {
            return "other";
        } else if (node === reference) {
            return "reference";
        }
    }

    var reference = thisNode,
        referenceTop = thisNode,
        otherTop = other;

    if (this === other) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (referenceTop.parentNode) {
        referenceTop = referenceTop.parentNode;
    }
    while (otherTop.parentNode) {
        otherTop = otherTop.parentNode;
    }

    if (referenceTop !== otherTop) {
        return DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED;
    }

    var children = reference.childNodes;
    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        children,
        function(p) {
            (function() {
                var localOther = other;
                return testNodeForComparePosition(localOther, p);
            })();
        }
    );
    if (ret) {
        return DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY +
            DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING;
    }

    var children = other.childNodes;
    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        children,
        function(p) {
            (function() {
                var localOther = reference;
                return testNodeForComparePosition(localOther, p);
            })();
        }
    );
    if (ret) {
        return DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS +
            DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING;
    }

    var ret = recursivelyWalk(
        [referenceTop],
        identifyWhichIsFirst
    );
    if (ret === "other") {
        return DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING;
    } else {
        return DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING;
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
compareDocumentPosition(sourceElement, elementToTest)
```

(It's like calling `sourceElement.compareDocumentPosition(elementToTest)`)