# Is element before or after another element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a means of detecting whether an element appears before or after another element in markup? This is *regardless* of position in DOM. It could be a child, a sibling, a parent or a parent's parent. This is a general question, so no markup to share.

To clarify - this is in regards to the element's position in markup, not its display position. Now that I think about it my question is a bit strange because if you have element X and element Y then you can have these scenarios.

```
//in regards to y
<x />
<y /> //:after

<y /> //:before
<x />

<x><y /></x> //not really before or after is it?
```

Comment: location in markup = location in DOM

Comment: What does after mean?  Do you mean after in the way in which a reader of that page's language would scan it?  So lower on the page OR at the same height and to the right for an English reader?

Comment: @MikeSamuel - I mean as if you actually printed out the markup. I guess there would be three states possible. before, after or child of (neither)

Comment: In your third example, `y` would typically be considered to be *after* `x`. DOM selection returns elements in document order, and so `x` will be considered to come first.

Comment: @mrtsherman - If you look at the 5 states given in the DOM spec and the answers listed here, they should cover all cases. Disconnected is just an equally important case - as you could have two nodes from different DOM's. Also `document order` as defined by the DOM spec simply means the order you'll encounter nodes in if you print out the entire HTML/XML on paper, and start going left to right till the end of a line, and then go down to the next line until you reach the end of all pages.

Comment: there's a cross browser shim for `node.compareDocumentPosition` written by @Raynos at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334758/6782

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, sort of. DOM3 introduced [`Node.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition), which allows you to compare the position of two elements. The functionality isn't very friendly: it involves bitmasks: this is a jQuery plugin that should simplify its use.

This code is only tested on Firefox 9 and the current version of Chromium. Certainly it won't work in old versions of IE.

```
$.fn.docPosition = function(element) {
    if (element.jquery) element = element[0];

    var position = this[0].compareDocumentPosition(element);

    if (position & 0x04) return 'after';
    if (position & 0x02) return 'before';
};
```

Also, an element that contains another is considered to be before it in the structure.

---

OK, a little Googling gives me [this blog post by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/) (the creator of jQuery), which includes compatibility with IE <9. (It's a little ugly: it uses two non-standard bits of functionality: `contains` and `sourceIndex`.)  This code should be cross-browser:

```
$.fn.docPosition = function (element) {
    function comparePosition(a, b) {
        return a.compareDocumentPosition ? 
          a.compareDocumentPosition(b) : 
          a.contains ? 
            (a != b && a.contains(b) && 16) + 
              (a != b && b.contains(a) && 8) + 
              (a.sourceIndex >= 0 && b.sourceIndex >= 0 ?
                (a.sourceIndex < b.sourceIndex && 4) + 
                  (a.sourceIndex > b.sourceIndex && 2) :
                1)
            + 0 : 0;
    }

    if (element.jquery) element = element[0];

    var position = comparePosition(this[0], element);

    if (position & 0x04) return 'after';
    if (position & 0x02) return 'before';
};
```

Comment: Instead of working with bitmasks, you can just reference the various constants involved such as Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition

Answer (score 8):

**[node.compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition)**

> **Summary**
>   Compares the position of the current node against another node in any other document.

**UPDATE**:
This does not work in all browsers but there is a fix for that. Thanks for Alnitak (see answer comments) for providing the link: [cross browser compare document position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334286/cross-browser-compare-document-position/8334758#8334758)

Comment: Bear in mind that this is not supported in IE < 9. I'm sure there are shims available though.

Comment: there's a cross browser shim for `node.compareDocumentPosition` written by @Raynos at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334758/6782

Answer (score 3):

A brute force approach may be to get all elements, then get the index of each element within the set.

```
var all = $('*');

var a_index = all.index($('#element_a'));
var b_index = all.index($('#element_b'));

if( a_index < b_index ) 
    alert( 'a is first' );
else
    alert( 'b is first' );
```

---

For a browser compliant non-jQuery solution, you could do this:

```
function sortInDocumentOrder( a, b ) {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

    for( var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i ) {
        if( all[i] === a )
            return [a,b];  
        else if( all[i] === b )
            return [b,a];
    }
}
```

Give it two elements, and it will return them in the document order.

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');

var inOrder = sortInDocumentOrder( a, b );
```

Comment: Clever. I am going to mess around with this. I asked the question on a whim so it will take me a little while to test use cases and be sure this is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have complete code, but the approach I would take (if `Node.compareDocumentPosition` isn't available) is:

1. obtain the `.parents()` chain of both elements
2. find the element furthest up each chain that's in both chains - this is the common parent
3. then check for the next element down each chain whether its index is before or after the other

There are tricks you could use to make (1) and (2) simpler by having the DOM do some of the work for you:

```
var $a = $('#a'); // first element
var $b = $('#b'); // first element

$a.parents().andSelf().addClass('search'); // mark A and all of A's ancestors
var $parent = $b.closest('.search');       // find B's first marked ancestor
```

Comment: I like this very much. Thank you for the creative idea. I will mess around with this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing a few things. The location in markup *is* the location in the DOM. This line shows your confusion:

```
<x><y /></x> //not really before or after is it?
```

Of course `y` is *after* `x` by any reasonable definition. You should think of the DOM as a tree, not as characters in a text file.

Now, as for determining position, use [`Node.compareDocumentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition):

```
node.compareDocumentPosition(otherNode)
```

The return value is a bitmask with the following values:

```
DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED = 0x01;
DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING = 0x02;
DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING = 0x04;
DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS = 0x08;
DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY = 0x16;
```

Comment: If we think of the DOM as a tree, then `y` could appear before `x` if we were to use in-order or post-order traversal. It just depends on what traversal method the spec implementors chose to use.

Answer (score 0):

This question requires a set of rules on what is considered *before* and *after*.  It's certainly easy to traverse the elements in `body` and see what comes next, but is there any sort of hierarchical precedence?  What about repeating elements?

```
<foo>
   <bar>
       <foobar />
   </bar>
</foo>
<foo>
   <baz />
</foo>
<foobar />
```

Does `baz` come before `foobar`?

I'd create two functions `isBefore` and `isAfter`; in this case they'd both be true (doing a depth first lookup).

---

```
var el = $('*');

function isBefore(elA, elB){
   return ( el.index($(elA).first()) < el.index($(elB).last()) );
}

function isAfter(elA, elB){
   return ( el.index($(elA).last()) > el.index($(elB).first()) );
}


isBefore('body', 'head'); // false
isAfter('body', 'head');  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full example with [Node.compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)

```
    /**
     * Checks if the node1 is before the node2 in the DOM tree
     * It is true if
     * + node1 is sibling before node2
     * + node1 contains node2
     * + node1 is in the subtree that is before node2 or the subtree that contains it
     */
    public isNodeBefore(node1: Node, node2: Node): boolean {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition
        return (node2.compareDocumentPosition(node1) & (Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING | Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS)) != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

An eazy way to know if element appears before other:
Use the sourceIndex property which retrieves the ordinal position of the object.

```
function isBefore(a, b){
   return a.sourceIndex < b.sourceIndex;
}

isBefore(head,body); //true
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Add some explanation, show where to put this line. Right now it's like comment "use sourceIndex"